# How to control the name of the HTML files that tex4ht uses for splitting subsubsections to?

Tags: tex4ht

I am trying to make my own links to targets in separate subsubsections. (I have reasons why I can't use tex4ht own links, since it does not work when splitting using separate files. Long story. I reported it but not possible to correct/fix using `xr-hyper`)

In the following, everything works well for splitting up to `subsection` level, since tex4ht uses format of name `insuNNN.htm` for the file names, where the main document is `index.tex` and `NNN` is a counter it increments sequentially for how many subsections there are in the whole document.

So doing the split at this level, I am able to figure the correct HTML file name to use.

The problem when I want to split at lower level. At the `subsubsection` level.

tex4ht for some reason, uses the same counter `NNNN` for `subsection` and also `subsubsection`.

And it keeps incrementing the counter.   So if `subsection` 10 was in file `insu10.htm`, then the next `subsubsection` will go to file `insu11.htm`

So my program, which wants to add a link to `subsubsection` is now not able to figure what the file name will be due to this.  It gets the counting wrong since it does not know how many subsections were before to compenate.

If tex4ht had used separate counter for `subsubsection`, then it will be possible to figure the file name and add correct link to it.

Note that tex4ht uses `inseMMM.htm` for sections. But uses `insuNNN.htm` format for both subsections and also subsubsection file name. And that is the main problem.

My question is, given I want to split at `subsubsection` level (i.e. split=5), is it possible to tell tex4ht to use one counter for this level and *not* share it with the subsection counter?

If so, then my program will be able to determine the correct file name and add a link to each problem correctly.

Here is MWE

```
\documentclass{book}

\begin{document}

\ifdefined\HCode 
  see problem \HCode{<a href="insu1.htm#1">1</a>} and problem \HCode{<a href="insu2.htm#2">2</a>}
  and problem \HCode{<a href="insu3.htm#3">3</a>}
\fi 

\chapter{this is chapter 1} 
\section{my first section} 
\subsection{my first subsection}
\subsubsection{my first subsubsection}
\ifdefined\HCode 
\HCode{<a id="1"></a>} 
\fi 
      this is problem 1
   
\section{my first section} 
\subsection{my second subsection}
\subsubsection{my second subsubsection}
\ifdefined\HCode 
\HCode{<a id="2"></a>} 
\fi 

      this is problem 2


\chapter{this is chapter 2} 
\section{my first section}
\subsection{my first subsection}
\subsubsection{my first subsubsection}
\ifdefined\HCode 
\HCode{<a id="3"></a>} 
\fi 

      this is problem 3
   
\end{document}
```

Compiling with

```
make4ht -ulm default -a debug index.tex 'htm,5'
```

Now links to `1` is off by 1, and link `2` is off by 2 and `3` are now off by 3 and so on.

For example the link to first subsubsection `insu1.htm` should be `insu2.htm` because texh4t used `insu1.htm` for the  intervening `subsection`.

It is not possible to figure these offsets in the program, due to this since the document is very complex and do not know how many subsections were used at different places to compensate for the counter drift.

But if the counter was sequential for each `subsubsection`, regardless of how `subsection` there are, then it will be possible to do what I want, I will simply have a global counter which I increase each time a new subsubsection is added and it will make life much simpler.

Is it possible to tell tex4ht or fix tex4ht to use different/unique counter for `subsubsection` splitting and not share the counter with `subsection`?

What I think tex4ht should do is this

`inchNNN.htm` for chapters (it does this already)

`inseNNN.htm` for sections (it does this already)

`insuNNN.htm` for subsections (it does this already)

`insuuNNN.htm` for `subsubsections` (this is the new change I am suggesting). Currently tex4ht uses same file name format and counter as `subsection`.

The above change will be very useful as it will make it much easier to add links to specific subsubsections in a document from outside.

TL 2022

Comment: Not sure, whether or not `tex4ebook` does provide a solution here already ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**

TeX4ht shortens generated filenames. It uses the first two characters of the `\jobname`, and the first two characters of the section type. The numeric suffix is attached to these to ensure unique names. In this case, `\subsection` and `\subsubsection` are both shortened to `su`. You can keep the full section type name in filename using this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\catcode`\:=11
\def\fx:pt#1xxx!*?: {%
   \expandafter\ifx \csname big:#1:\endcsname\relax
         \expandafter\gHAssign\csname big:#1:\endcsname  0  \fi
   \expandafter\gHAdvance\csname big:#1:\endcsname  1
   \edef\big:fn{#1\csname big:#1:\endcsname}}
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It is a redefinition of the internal TeX4ht command that shortens the section type name. In this version, it just keeps the full name.

These are resulting filenames:

```
./index.htm
./inchapter1.htm
./inchapter2.htm
./insection1.htm
./insection2.htm
./insection3.htm
./insubsection1.htm
./insubsection2.htm
./insubsection3.htm
./insubsubsection1.htm
./insubsubsection2.htm
./insubsubsection3.htm
./insubsubsection4.htm
```

I've also added the `cut-fullname` option to TeX4ht sources, so after TeX Live update, it will be possible to get the same effect using:

```
 $ make4ht -ulm default -a debug index.tex 'htm,5,cut-fullname'
```

**Original:**

The correct solution for this problem is to use the `sec-filename` option. It names files according to the current top section title:

```
 $ make4ht -ulm default -a debug index.tex 'htm,5,sec-filename'
```

It generates the following files:

```
./index.htm
./myfirstsection.htm
./myfirstsection1.htm
./myfirstsection2.htm
./myfirstsubsection.htm
./myfirstsubsection1.htm
./myfirstsubsubsection.htm
./myfirstsubsubsection1.htm
./mysecondsubsection.htm
./mysecondsubsubsection.htm
./mysecondsubsubsection1.htm
./thisischapter1.htm
./thisischapter2.htm
```

As you can see, it uses section titles. It removes spaces and other non-alphanumeric characters, and if file with the same name already exists, it adds a numeric suffix, to ensure a unique filename.

Thanks for that, you don't need to update your links every time you add a new section (unless there already is one with the same name).

Comment: I did not know about `sec-filename` but I am afraid this makes things worst for me. Now I have to know what each subsubsection name actually is from outside the document I am trying to link to.  using `insuuNNN` would be the perfect solution, since for me `NNN` is the problem number. So I could just say from outside, `see problem <a \href="insuNNN.htm#NNN>etc...</a>" for problem NNN` where NNN is the problem number which is one global counter I have that goes from 1 to say 100. I put each problem in its own subsubsection. But now I have to know what each subsubsection title is.  Thanks,.

Comment: Is it hard to make tex4ht just generate files with names `insuuNNN.htm` for subsubsection and not share `insuNNN,htm` with subsections? This would be a much better way to do it. At least it will be easier, since the file name is known, and just need to add the problem number to get the full name without having to know the exact title used.

Comment: @Nasser it probably shouldn't be that hard, it is just that `sec-filename` already exists and I thought that it would be a better solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this option, But the issue is that I am trying to build separate chapters on their own to speed tex4ht on large documents. But I need to be able to add links to specific problem(s) from outside. I only know the problem number from outside. The titles themselves change from chapter to chapter. If it is possible to make subsubsection use its own file format with its own counter that will be great.  I have been running tex4ht for now 5 days on this one large file and it is on iteration 36 and not finished yet. So I need a way to speed this process :(

Comment: I think the checksum is not working right btw. I do not understand why the current build I am running needs 36 iterations to get everything sorted out.  But I am using your build file, and I set the maximum to 100 (it was 3 before) and it is still running and now at iteration 36. There seems to be a problem with how checksum is done but not sure. Hopefully will find out if it finished  in 2-3 weeks.

Comment: @Nasser the checksum thing seems like a bug, 36 is nonsensically big number.

Comment: hi Michal. Agree but I am waiting to see the result when it is done. Please see screen shot  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xsVx.png)  I am running this on Ubuntu 22.04 under WSL 2.0 under windows 10 linux subsystem using TL 2022.

Comment: @Nasser I've also found that there is a hard limit on the number of files that TeX4ht can generate. I think you had a problem with the number of files where it mysteriously fail after some section, but I cannot find it now. Do you remember that?

Comment: I am glad you found that. This explains all the problems I;ve been having with missing table of content for last chapter. It only shows first section but there are 9 more. Will send you email now on this and link.  Thanks.

Comment: That is a great solution Michal by adding `cut-fullname` option.  Yes, `insubsubsectionNNN.htm` is good solution. Now it will be possible to add links to the document from outside, by knowing only the problem number `NNN` and nothing else. I will try this as soon as I can. This will allow me to shorten the build time by building only the changed chapters. Thanks.

Comment: @Nasser that's great to hear! Note that the `cut-filename` will not shorten also the `\jobname`, so links will become `indexsection1.html` etc.

Comment: Yes, thanks for this. It made life much easier. But I am still struggling with xr-hyper. I send email on this to mailing list. I hope you'll have sometime to look at it.   Thank you.