# Make4HT - Required Output HTML File specific Name

Tags: luatex, tex4ebook

I have using `Make4Ht` for Converting `LaTeX to HTML` and it's working great.

I would like to expect the `HTML filename` with specific Name instead of generated HTML filename. I have mentioned required output html filename here     `\input{domes-ack}% Expect Output HTML FileName is : 9780132132-fm02.xhtml`.

How to achieve this? My command is:

`tex4ebook -m draft -a -debug -f epub3 filename.tex`.

```
\documentclass{acm-book-v1}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
Book Title Here
ISBN : 9780132132
ISSN : 9701
DOI : 10.2341/9701
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\input{domes-preface}% Expect Output HTML FileName is : 9780132132-fm01.xhtml
\listoffigures
\input{domes-ack}% Expect Output HTML FileName is : 9780132132-fm02.xhtml
\listoftables
\input{Intro}% Expect Output HTML FileName is : 9780132132-fm03.xhtml
\mainmatter
\chapter{Title Here}
\input{Chapter01}% Expect Output HTML FileName is : 9780132132-Ch01.xhtml
\section{Section Here}\label{1=1}
\include{domes-Chapter02}% Expect Output HTML FileName is : 9780132132-Ch02.xhtml
\backmatter
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-j` or `--jobname` option to rename the output file. It works with both `tex4ebook` and `make4ht`. Your command  can look like this:

```
 tex4ebook -j  9780132132-fm02 -m draft -a -debug -f epub3 filename.tex
```

Comment: I have Root LaTeX file(ex: Main.tex) with `\include` or `\input` LaTeX file(Ex: input{Intro} and \include{domes-Chapter02}`. I would like final output HTML filename is `ISBN-ChapterNo` or `ISBN-FM-Parts`. How to get this?

Comment: So you want to produce separate files for chapters and sections, named after their titles? Try the `sec-filename` option.

Comment: I have used `tex4ebook -a fatal filename.tex "xhtml,fn-in,sec-filename,mathml,mathjax"`. But it's not generating separate `HTML` filename. How to get and please advise.

Comment: `tex4ebook` generates Epub, you may want to use `make4ht` if you want html. try `make4ht -f xhtml -a fatal filename.tex ""xhtml,fn-in,sec-filename,mathml,mathjax,3"`

Comment: I have created `html` file used `tex4ht`. How to change the filename `filenamech1.html` to `filenamechapter1.html`?

Comment: @Balaji try the `cut-fullname` option

Comment: Thanks and I have found your answer <https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644059/how-to-control-the-name-of-the-html-files-that-tex4ht-uses-for-splitting-subsubs> it's very useful for me.