# Expect Output HTML filename same as Input/Include

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht, tex4ebook

Expect the final output html filename is same as `\include` filename or `\input` filename. How to get this using `make4ht`. I had referred this link [How to control the name of the HTML files that tex4ht uses for splitting subsubsections to?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644059/how-to-control-the-name-of-the-html-files-that-tex4ht-uses-for-splitting-subsubs) and not full requirements as expected.

My MWE IS:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum,imakeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\input{1234567890-bkseries}% Expect HTML Output FileName is 1234567890-bkseries.html
\title{Computing for Interactive}
\author{Parisa}
\input{1234567890-cpright}% Expect HTML Output FileName is 1234567890-cpright.html
\mainmatter
\include{1234567890-Intro}% Expect HTML Output FileName is 1234567890-Intro.html
\include{0987654321-Ch_01}% Expect HTML Output FileName is 1234567890-Intro.html
\include{1234567890-Ch_01_1E}% Expect HTML Output FileName is 1234567890-Intro.html
\backmatter
\input{0987654321-Author-Bio}% Expect HTML Output FileName is 1234567890-Intro.html
\printindex
\end{document}
```

[How to control the name of the HTML files that tex4ht uses for splitting subsubsections to?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644059/how-to-control-the-name-of-the-html-files-that-tex4ht-uses-for-splitting-subsubs)

Comment: You expect some `\input` and `\include` commands to produce different names than the included filenames. How could you detect it?

Comment: @michal.h21: Okay. Then, I can use only `\include` command how to get the filename?

Comment: you can use any command you want, it will just use the name of the included file to create a new html file with the same name everytime

Comment: @michal.h21: I have using `make4ht -j \jobname`. My Root LaTeX FileName is `MyRoot.TeX` and it's having `\include{Ch01-bkse}` and `\include{Ch02-Biblio}`. I have expecting the final HTML filename is `MyRoot.HTML`, `Ch01-bkse.html` and `Ch02-Biblio.html`. How to get this filename?

Comment: Does all these include files start with new chapters?

Comment: @michal.h21: Yes. When I have using `\include` it can be `\chapter{` or `\chapter*{` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your included files starts with the `\chapter` command, you can use the following configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,2}
\Configure{CutAt-filename}{%
  \filename@parse\CurrentFile%
  \NextFile{\filename@base.html}%
}

\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

The `2` option in the `\Preamble` command will ensure that all chapters will be saved in separate HTML pages. The `\Configure{CutAt-filename}` configuration sets the name for these chapter pages. We use LaTeX's command `\filename@parse` to extract the name of the currently used file without extension. This filename is then used in the `\NextFile` command, which sets the name of the chapter file.

This approach has one issue - you need to use the `\chapter` command only inside included files, and each included file can contain only one chapter, otherwise the subsequent chapter will overwrite the first chapter in the given file. If you want to support multiple chapters, the code would be a little more complicated, as you would need to check if the current name was used previously, and handle it accordingly.